# Get select selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a url like this:
`index.php/home/lista_modelo_ajax?id="+$('#colecoes').val(),`

The thing is that the: `$('#colecoes').val()` is always the first item of the select, not the one I choose.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
            $( "#modelos" ).autocomplete({
                source: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/home/lista_modelo_ajax?id="+$('#colecoes').val(),
                minLength: 2
            });
    });
    </script>


<label for="colecoes">Coleções</label>
        <select name="colecoes" id="colecoes">
            <option value="16">-</option>
            <?php foreach($lista_colecao as $colecao){?>
            <option value="<?php echo $colecao->idColecao;?>"><?php echo $colecao->nomeColecao;?></option>
            <?php }?>
        </select>
        <label for="modelos">Modelo</label>
        <input type="text" name="modelos" id="modelos" />
```

All php is working fine, generating the IDs on the value of options objects, the problem is only with JS

Comment: have you tried `$('#colecoes').val()` or `$('#colecoes :selected).val()`? just a guess...

Comment: You mentioned $('#colecoes option:selected').val() in the question but cannot find it anywhere in the code.

Comment: I have edited it, sorry for not mentioning it =/

Comment: Looks like you want to get the autocomplete data from the PHP URL and it depends on the option selected. Have you tried Darin Dimitrov's answer? Try replacing the first $ in your script with $('#colecoes').change

Comment: @Cracker yes..but it's not working...and there is no error messages from on the browser

Comment: Please add a comment to Darin's answer so that he knows that it doesn't work and can think further. 
I have never used the autocomplete plugin. Quick googling led me to http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions and I do not find the options you are using in it. Can you provide a reference to the autocomplete plugin?

Comment: @Gerep let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1243/discussion-between-cracker-and-gerep)

Comment: @Cracker http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: Click the link and join the chat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend on where you are writing this code. If you are writing it directly in the document ready that would be normal as at the moment this code executes that's the selected value. On the other hand if you are writing it for example in the .change event of the dropdown list you will get the actual value:

```
$('#colecoes').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val(); // now you will get the actual selected value
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php/home/lista_modelo_ajax',
        data: { id: id },
        success: function(result) {
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Gerep, *it didn't work* is not very precise. What didn't work? Is your PHP script not getting the id variable or something? Did you put this `.change` handler subscription inside a `$(document).ready` handler in order to ensure that your DOM has been loaded before trying to attach any handlers to it?

Comment: your code will not work because I need to use .autoload function from jqueryUI....and yes...php is not receiving anything

Comment: @Gerep, maybe this performs a POST AJAX request so you need to adapt your PHP script to read the id from the POST body, or impose GET request by setting `type: 'GET'`, so that the id is sent as query string parameter.

Comment: I had a chat with Cracker and he showed me that your code was correct, I just had to change your ajax function by my .autoload, thanks a lot for your patience =)

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
$('#colecoes').val(); //assuming `colecoes` is the id of the select
```

Example with onchange:

```
$('#colecoes').change(function(){
    alert(this.value); //alerts the selected option
});
```